# VBScript to detect VSS Exchange Writer State

Tags: exchange, vbscript, vss

I need to detect the state of the Exchange VSS Writer service on a given machine.  The script will only be executed if Microsoft Exchange 2003, 2007, or 2010 is currently running.

Powershell Script execution is not a viable option, as the client environments may or may not have script execution enabled.

Currently, I capture the output of running this command:

```
cmd /C "vssadmin list writers | find "Microsoft Exchange Writer" | find "State"
```

and if the state is set, return true.

This is always return true, because the first find only returns a single line.

Comment: Basically I need to get trailing lines to "Microsoft Exchange Writer"... Anyone know any flags/options/regex so I can grab trailing lines in the Find command?

Comment: I think this can be done with some combination of findstr instead of find.  I am not currently finding any way to build a regex that spans multiple lines.  Anyone have any clue on how to construct that?